# Бильярд. Управление мышью С++

Tags: c++

Я пишу свой бильярд на с++. Помогите реализовать логику с управление главным шаром с помощью мыши. Как бы шар покатиться в ту сторону куда направлена мышь. Не могу придумать даже логику этого действия. Думал через координаты, но не получилось.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том что я не могу получить адекватные координаты курсора и шара. Причина в том что они находятся в разных координатных системах. В моем приложении (картинка 2) система начинается с середины экрана и шар находиться на координатах(например [0,-4.5]) и если я возьму координаты курсора с помощью GetCursorPos(&p) или ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p), то они просто не сопоставятся. Поэтому я был бы рад возможно вообще другому решению.

Comment: Нажать кнопку на шаре. Потянуть в нужном направлении. Отпустить — вот и направление, и (длина) сила удара...

Comment: Да, у меня уже есть логика силу удара. Я не понимаю как получить направление относительно шара к курсору на с++. Грубо говоря как на картинке. Где курсор это кий и если я буду двигать курсор вокруг шара то и кий будет перемещаться.

Comment: @Harry Ваша идея мне нравиться, но я не понимаю как её реализовать её. Её можно реализовать её как то через MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE?

Comment: `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` — записываем координаты, `MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP` — записываем вторые координаты, находим из *двух* координат все, что нужно... Кий двигайте так, чтоб он был продолжением направления удара.

Comment: @Harry Я попробовал, но почему то они возвращают всегда одинаковые числа. Простите, можно попросить вас расписать подробнее. Я к сожалению не нашел документации по этим методам.

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Как из координат мышки и шара получить угол?

Comment: Нет, у меня не получается получить сами координаты. Или по другому говоря они не корректны.

Comment: Не забывайте `@username`, а то уведомления не приходят.

Comment: Ну так вы же как-то переводите шар в оконные координаты, чтобы его нарисовать. Значит и обратное преобразование должно быть возможно сделать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Хорошо, попробую что-нибудь реализовать и отпишусь завтра.

Comment: Мне кажется тут нужна формула (алгоритм) траектории линии ПОШАГОВО. Если у кого есть такова, поделитесь. Мне как-то написали формулу, но я её потерял :( С её помощью можно было ПКМ на экране и объект двигался туда. В формуле была константа, на сколько пикселей за раз смещаться (скорость). Поделитесь такой формулой, в GameDev это очень нужно!

Comment: Вам еще нужно будет потом написать некую физику, шары бьются друг о друга, придавая инерцию :) Меняя траектории в разные стороны, коллизии и т.п. Просто потренироваться? В UNITY всё уже готовое есть, физика, траектории, коллизии и т.д. C# в UNITY не сложный. Процесс самопознания и "как это всё работает" интересен ;)